# fpm: issue packaging binary files

Tags: rpmbuild, fpmake

It seems binary file that was packaged using Fpm has a different checksum from original file. And as result can not be executed. I read entire documentation and tried to "play" with compression formats with no luck.

Comment: What is stopping the execution?

Answer (score 0):

RPM will do things to the file like remove debugging info, so the checksum won't match one that you build yourself.